# Testing an OSGi bundle with JUnit via ant task

Tags: ant, junit, osgi

I'm looking for the easiest way to be able to run junit tests via ant task where the unit tests are defined in an OSGi bundle.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
DR

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how integration testing works in [BndTools](http://bndtools.org). Tests are junit tests, but run in an OSGi container. The tests can run from ANT as well out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pax-exam, it should also work with ant.
https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam